# Problems trying to turn on auto-fill in a directory local way

Tags: directory-local-variables, auto-fill-mode

I am inexperienced in Emacs and very new to directory-local variables, so please forgive any obvious things I may be missing.

I am trying to have auto-fill mode activated for all the files in a certain directory.  In this directory, I have a `.dir-locals.el` file which contains:

```
((nil . ((eval add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
     (truncate-lines . nil)))
)
```

(FYI I have `truncate-lines` set to `t` in my `.emacs` file, so that's its "default" value for me.)

After saving this `.dir-locals.el` file, when opening a text file with Emacs in this directory, I find that `truncate-lines` is indeed turned off.  However, `auto-fill` isn't working: the lines I'm writing don't break into new lines.  (My `fill-column` value is 70.)

When I do `C-h v text-mode-hook` I get:

```
text-mode-hook's value is 
(turn-on-auto-fill text-mode-hook-identify)
...
```

but when I don't include the "`eval add-hook`..." in the `.dir-locals.el` file, the words `turn-on-auto-fill` don't appear in the `text-mode-hook`'s value, so the `.el` file I have appears to be setting something, it just isn't working.

When I do `M-x auto-fill-mode`, then `auto-fill` does start working.

Any ideas why `auto-fill` isn't working for me from my directory local file?  Alternatively, any suggestions for an alternative way to active `auto-fill-mode` for and only for the files in my directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory local variables are set after the major mode command run. Otherwise the major-mode dependent file local variables would not work.

Therefore, you just buffer-locally add `turn-on-auto-fill` to `text-mode-hook`. But the hook is not run again and your configuration is without effect.

If you want to deactivate `truncate-lines` for all major modes and activate `auto-fill-mode` just for `text-mode` in a certain directory (and its sub-directories) you can put the following list into your `.dir-locals.el`-file:

```el
((nil . ((truncate-lines . t)))
 (text-mode . ((eval . (turn-on-auto-fill)))))
```